# Cross origin inside chrome extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I'm working on an extension that records loading time of web pages inside an iframe. I used the performance timing api to do that. At the beginning I wanted to do that without extension but it was impossible even if I used a proxy and modify on the fly the html source code of the iframe. I worked on the problem for a pretty long time.

So I tryed to do that with a Chrome Extension. The result is pretty good for the loading time of the main iframe but I had always error raised like (example of an embedded video inside the iframe)

```
`locked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://cdiekdckgbgmndanblnkodcjnbkdcmmc".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.`
```

I used a content script for recording load time and sent the result via postmessage to the mainframe page. The mainframe page is only used to display information of loading time to the user. I know that I can delete the mainframe an used directly chrome ui (notification system for exemple) but I want to find something usefull to create IE and Firefox extension.

extract of manifest.json

```
"permissions": [ "*://*/*", "webRequest", "tabs", "storage" ]
"content_scripts": [ {
  "js": [ "js/content.js" ],
  "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
  "all_frames": true,
  "run_at": "document_start"
} ]
```

Comment: Why don't you just hook into the DOM directly to do your measurements? I don't understand why you'd need an `iframe`.

Comment: Check out the [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html) API, and see if it covers your needs.

Comment: In fact I need the iframe to display in real time information to the user.

Comment: I have the same problem.. Please share if you have something useful in this regard.